# @Autowired JSF 2 Spring 3 Null

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, code-injection

I am not able to inject the service using the @Autowired.

AplicationContext.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.bean" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.filters" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

faces-config.xml

```
    <application>
     <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver></application>
```

web.xml

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Service declaration:

```
    @Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl implements UsuarioService{...}
```

ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="cadastroUsuarioMB")
@SessionScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    public String salvar() {
                //Error !!! usuarioService is null !
        usuarioService.retornaUsuarioPorLogin(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha());
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(null, usuario.getCelular());
        return "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That error is because UsuarioService is spring context managed bean and @ManagedBean is jsf managed bean. Either
1)replace @ManagedBean with @Component to make @Autowire inject the service or
2)

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{usuarioService}")
private UsuarioService usuarioService ; // mutators for this.
}
```

Comment: I Solved ! replace @ManagedBean(name="cadastroUsuarioMB") to @Component("cadastroUsuarioMB")

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file **AplicationContext.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.bean" />
```

Need to put the annotation "**@Controller**" on your Bean

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean(name="cadastroUsuarioMB")
@SessionScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    public String salvar() {
                //Error !!! usuarioService is null !
        usuarioService.retornaUsuarioPorLogin(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha());
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(null, usuario.getCelular());
        return "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject your **service**  by using Spring, So you have to change the declaration in the above of your controller.

replace `@ManagedBean(name="cadastroUsuarioMB")` by `@Component("cadastroUsuarioMB")` like this you inform Spring container to manage the injection and not JSF container.